# C++ OpenCV, very slow read() FPS, after moving to OpenCV4

Tags: c++, opencv, frame-rate

So currently all I am doing is just rewriting old methods that were using C OpenCV (not even2).
It was nicely running at 1920x1080 with 30fps. But as I am refactoring it want to move to latest libraries.

So Hardware is the same, and so far logic and everything is the same too. except previously to capture the frame I was using `cvQueryFrame` and `cvCaptureFromCAM` and currently it's:

```
CameraController::CameraController(Config& config) : _config(config)
{

    _cam = VideoCapture(0);
    _cam.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, _config.get<int>("camWidth"));
    _cam.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, _config.get<int>("camHeight"));
    _cam.set(CAP_PROP_FPS, _config.get<int>("camFPS"));  //30 FPS, tried without it
    _cam.set(CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 2);  // tried without it 
}

void CameraController::capture()
{
    _cam.read(_frame);
}
```

I have thread running like:

```
ptime currentTime = microsec_clock::local_time();
        float deltaTime = (currentTime - m_prevTime).total_microseconds() / 1000000.0f; // to seconds
        if (deltaTime > 1)
            deltaTime = 0;

        //Capture frame
        _cam.capture();

// Reset timer match desired FPS
        m_loopTimer.expires_from_now(milliseconds((1/_config.get<int>("camFPS"))) * 1000); //to match desired fps (previously was 16ms and no difference)
        m_loopTimer.async_wait(boost::bind(&UpdateController::UpdateLoop, this));
        m_prevTime = currentTime;
```

And with `1920x1080` I get 5-7 fps. With lowest resolution I am able to get 30fps, but that's not what I want.
Why is this happening ?

Comment: where is the time spent?

Comment: What do you mean by time spent ? ` m_loopTimer.expires_from_now(milliseconds((1/_config.get<int>("camFPS"))) * 1000);` this is to rerun update after ( in case of 30fps, after 33ms)

Comment: that's the issue. you must not sleep/wait. VideoCapture::read must run often enough to collect frames such that they DO NOT queue up in the driver. there may also be the case that video capture simply can't go faster than what you see because it does color space conversions implicitly, and those cost time.

Comment: But I do run it every 33ms, that, should be fast enough, I tried 16ms and that does not change anything. I am just confused, because I was using old capture From Cam C function and that was working just fine. All I did is changed it to Video Capture. I lowered resolution a notch, and it seems to be solid 30fps, but it's just weird I can't get it in full HD.

Comment: `expires_from_now` means you wait 33 ms, but that is in addition to the time spent on VideoCapture::read. try 0 ms and check precisely what frame rate you get, and by how much it differs vs. the original code.

Comment: Ah, I get you, so read is not "async". I will try your suggestion

Comment: correct. it's not entirely async. there *can* be some color space conversion right in the read call. if there is a queued frame, it uses that (and does the conversion if needed). if there isn't a frame, it will wait until one is created by the camera. frames can and will queue up in most drivers if you don't read them quickly enough.

Comment: I removed awaiting, and looks like I get solid 30fps without any additional processing. Nice one.  Btw in the mean time I actually had to force using MJPG codec  to get more than 7FPS, but then still wasn't full 30 FPS until now and your suggestion. 
All makes sense now. Thank you